# psql CREATE TABLESPACE shows syntax error

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, tablespace

I tried to create a tablespace in a directory to store my databases but it returns syntax error everytime.

I entered :

```
CREATE TABLESPACE "general"
LOCATION "/media/tahnoon/qwerty/Data/PSQL DATABASES";
```

And it returned :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""/media/tahnoon/qwerty/Data/PSQL DATABASES""
LINE 2: LOCATION "/media/tahnoon/qwerty/Data/PSQL DATABASES";
```

I tried chown-ing the directory by :

```
sudo chown postgres:tahnoon PSQL\ DATABASES/
```

But it still doesn't work.
Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument after `LOCATION` must be enclosed inside single quotes, not double quotes.

See the synopsis and examples in the [CREATE TABLESPACE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtablespace.html) documentation:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tablespace_name
    [ OWNER { new_owner | CURRENT_USER | SESSION_USER } ]
    LOCATION 'directory'
    [ WITH ( tablespace_option = value [, ... ] ) ]
```